# How to hide the cancel button on an ASP.NET ChangePassword control

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I'm considering using the ChangePassword control on an ASP.NET 2.0 Webform.  I don't want the 'cancel' button to show.

Is there a good way to hide it without resorting to silly "width = 0" sort of games?

Or perhaps there's a generic way to walk through the parts of a composite control like this 
and hide individual parts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set CancelButtonStyle.CssClass to something like "hiddenItem" and set the CSS to "display:none".

Otherwise you can convert the control to a template and simply delete away the cancel-button manually. When you click the control in Design-mode in Visual Studio, you get a little arrow with options and one of them is "Convert to Template".

Answer (score 3):

A quick an easy way just using your .aspx page is to set these cancel button properties on the changepassword control:

CancelButtonType="Link"
CancelButtonText=""

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ChangePassword.CancelButtonStyle Property to set the CSS-class on the Cancel Button. Then just apply "display: none" on the specified class.

Comment: ChangePassword.CancelButtonStyle is a read-only property...use ChangePassword.CancelButtonStyle.CssClass as per above.